# Adobe Reader Error Codes

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am programmatically creating PDFs, and a recent change to my generator is creating documents that crash both Mac Preview and Adobe Reader on my Mac.  Before Adobe Reader crashes, it reports:

> There was an error processing a page.
>   There was a problem reading this document (18).

I suspect that that "18" might give me some information on what is wrong with the PDF I've created.  Is there a document explaining the meaning of these status codes?

Answer (score 5):

Hold down the Ctrl key while pressing OK and you should be able to load past this point in the document and possibly get more details.

What tool are you using to create the PDF (Aspose)?

Comment: I'm using CAM::PDF and there was a problem with how it copied objects from one document to another, which was creating a circular reference.  I'm going to post an answer describing what I did to track down the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to locate any info on the Adobe error code, so I ended up installing [xpdf via Darwinports](http://xpdf.darwinports.com/).  Loading my PDF with xpdf spit out much more useful error information and I was able to track down the problem.  (I was creating a circular reference in a form when I copied content from one document to another.)